# Trying to console.log data within useEffect. Not logging any information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, atomicassets

```
function UserAccounts() {
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchAccounts() {
      const res = await fetch(
        'https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/accounts'
      );
      const { accounts } = await res.json();

      setAccounts(accounts);
      console.log(accounts);
    }

    fetchAccounts();
  }, []);
 
}
```

I'm trying to understand why console.log shows nothing in this example and what is the correct way to console.log the data that is being fetched from the api.

Comment: You never call `fetchAccounts()`

Comment: My mistake. I edited my post.

Comment: see setState functions run asynchronousely so this is never gonna get value returned from ajax

Comment: @AmirRahman looks right to me. OP is logging the local `accounts` variable, not the state one. I don't recommend variable shadowing but that's a style choice

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"shows nothing"_? Try giving it a label to make it more obvious... `console.log("fetchAccounts", accounts)`. What exactly does it show? Does the request succeed or are there uncaught promise rejection errors reported?

Comment: What I mean by "shows nothing" is that no information is logged to my console. I am simply trying to see what the payload looks like. Someone else used **JSON.stringify** to see the payload, and that works, but I was curious as to why console.log wasn't working.

Comment: @Mooch did you add a label to your `console.log()` [as suggested earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71330744/trying-to-console-log-data-within-useeffect-not-logging-any-information#comment126083979_71330744)? If so, what **exactly** gets logged? I would expect _"fetchAccounts undefined"_. If not, then you either have errors you're ignoring, your actual code doesn't look like the code in your question _or_ you've enabled log filtering in your browser's console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you need to get the structure of the returned payload from the API correct. It does not have an `accounts` property.

The payload looks like this:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "data":[{"account":"joejerde","assets":"11933"},{"account":"protonpunks","assets":"9072"}],
  "queryTime": 1646267075822
}
```

So you can rename the `data` property while destructuring. `const { data: accountList } = await res.json();`

```
function UserAccounts() {
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchAccounts() {
      const res = await fetch(
        'https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/accounts'
      );
      const { data: accountList } = await res.json();

      setAccounts(accountList);

      // logging both the state and the fetched value
      console.log(accounts, accountList);
      // accounts (state) will be undefined
      // if the fetch was successful, accountList will be an array of accounts (as per the API payload)
    }

    fetchAccounts()
  
  }, [])

  return <div>
    {JSON.stringify(accounts)}
  </div>
}
```

Edit: using some other variable name while destructuring, confusing to use the same variable name as the state (`accounts`).

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-data-from-api-xzzxpp?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Although I do see the data on the page using the **JSON.strigify**, I'm still not seeing it log out to the console.

Comment: Don't bother logging `accounts`, it will only show the old value

Comment: Exactly, as Phil said, React will ensure that you see the result of `setState` in the next render. So using the value in render will make it visible.

Comment: @Mooch what do you want to log out? The fetched data or the current state value?

Comment: @Shreshth I'm trying to log out the console to see the fetched data.

Comment: @Mooch I have updated my answer to show which variable will log what.

Comment: @Shreshth. Thank you. Also, how were you able to see the payload the way that you did. Normally I do this with console.log. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Since it's a `GET` request, just visiting the link will give the payload as raw text. Visit this link: https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/accounts

Comment: Also, `console.log` works fine too. You could have logged the fetch response before destructuring to see it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would change is working with try/catch surrounding async/await statements.
If your await statement fails it will never reach the console.log statement.
Unless you have another component handling those errors, I would use it in that way.

That is my suggestion:

```js
function UserAccounts() {
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
     async function fetchAccounts() {
      const res = await fetch(
        'https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/accounts'
      );
      const { accounts } = await res.json();

      setAccounts(accounts);
      console.log(accounts);
     }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      // do something like throw your error
    }

    fetchAccounts();
  }, []);
 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

since state function runs asyncronousely . therefore when you use `setAccounts` it sets `accounts` variable in async way , so there is a preferred way of doing this thing is as below

problems i seen

**1.fetch result should destructured with data instead of accounts variable**

**2.setAccounts function is running async way so it will not print result immedietly in next line**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState();

  async function fetchAccounts() {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/accounts"
    );
    const { data } = await res.json();
    setAccounts(data);
  }

  // on component mount / onload
  useState(() => {
    fetchAccounts();
  }, []);

  // on accounts state change
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(accounts);
  }, [accounts]);

  return <div className="blankElement">hello world</div>;
}
```

check here [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-sutherland-ftgbry?file=/src/App.js:0-570)

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, OP is logging the local `accounts` variable, not the state one.

Comment: as i can see accounts variable is used once for state and also used for fetch result how it will work and it should clealy be loggin error in console thats confusing

Comment: @Phil and bro what i posted is about how things should be implemented in react fetch results are supposed to be stored in state and then later used in markup and not directly from fetch result its good to work via state for future prof code thats what i showed

Comment: @Mooch check updated answer